# High quality book covers using Google Books API

Tags: google-books-api

[According to the Google Books API documentation](https://developers.google.com/books/docs/v1/reference/volumes) each volume yields 6 different imageLinks (smallThumbnail, thumbnail, small, medium, large, extraLarge).

Unfortunately, for all the queries I've tried (and I've tried a lot) only `smallThumbnail` and `thumbnail` were returned. ([Example query](https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=Great%20Expectations&orderBy=relevance&printType=BOOKS))

Also, apart from being fairly small those two images have this little fake dog-ears in the bottom right corner

[image: Example thumbnail]

Did they deprecate the high quality image links? Is there another way to fetch those images? Other APIs I tried are either deprecated (Goodreads) or less extensive (Open Library)

Answer (score 3):

I'm having the same issue. The search query only yields the smallThumbnail and thumbnail keys for the imageLinks. If you query the volume directly (like [this](https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/aMwAEAAAQBAJ?fields=id,volumeInfo(title,imageLinks))), then you'll get all the options for the imageLinks.

This won't 100% solve your problem though. For some of the books, the small/medium/large links point to the first page of the book instead of the actual cover.

Answer (score 3):

You might not be able to get high-resolution images all the time. Also, for some book results, you might not get any images at all.

I am working on a similar project and I had to manually check the resolution of each of the images I got in the response and I chose only the 'good' ones.
Here's what I had to do:

```
        let newArr = [];
        let lowResImage = 0;
        let dataWithoutImage = 0;
        let highResImage = 0;
genreResults?.forEach((book, index) => {

        if (book?.volumeInfo?.imageLinks?.smallThumbnail) {//the current book has an image

            mypromise(book.volumeInfo.imageLinks.smallThumbnail).then((res) => {
                ++highResImage;
                newArr.push(book)
            }).catch(error => {
                ++lowResImage;
            }).finally(() => {
                if (dataWithoutImage + highResImage + lowResImage === genreResults.length) {
                    console.log("---------data populated----------");
                    console.log("highResolutionImages", highResImage);
                    console.log("low resolution images:", lowResImage);
                    console.log("booksWithoutImages", dataWithoutImage);
                    console.log("genreResults size", genreResults.length)
                    setBooks(newArr)
                }
            });

        }
        else //this book does not contain an image
            ++dataWithoutImage

    })
```

The function to check the resolution looks like this:

```
let mypromise = function checkImageResolution(url) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = url;
        img.onload = function () {
            console.log("image dimensions", this.width, this.height);
            if (this.width < 125 || this.height < 100) //if either of these is true, reject the image
                reject("low quality image");
            else
                resolve("high quality ,let's have this one");
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the following:

```
thumbnail=thumbnail.replaceAll("1","10");
```

But it works only for some books and for the remaining it will only load the first page of the book.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the [help]. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites.